# With EclipseLink how do you disable automatic uppercase conversion on creation

Tags: eclipselink, ddl

When using EclipseLink for ddl generation, it always default column and table names to uppercase. 
Is there a way to disable this globally rather than setting each columns name attribute? , or to make it use the Class name, or your own column name serializer?

Thanks a lot!

EclipseLink output
[EL Config]: metadata: The column name for element [warehouseCreatedTimestamp] is being defaulted to: WAREHOUSECREATEDTIMESTAMP.

The table name for entity [class entities.ActivityFlags] is being defaulted to: ACTIVITYFLAGS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be disabled by configuration:
https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/p_jpa_uppercase_column_names.htm

in persistence.xml or code (as usual)

```
 <property name="eclipselink.jpa.uppercase-column-names" value="false"/>
```

If You want implement selective rule, implement in code

```
org.eclipse.persistence.dynamic.DynamicHelper.SessionCustomizer
```

My fragment add underscores to tables by specific rule.  Columns are possible too.

```
public class MySessionCustomizer extends SessionCustomizer {

@Override
public void customize(Session session) throws SQLException {


    for (ClassDescriptor descriptor : session.getDescriptors().values()) {
        // Only change the table name for non-embedable entities with no
        // @Table already
        if (!descriptor.getTables().isEmpty() && descriptor.getAlias().equalsIgnoreCase(descriptor.getTableName())) {
            String tableName = addUnderscores(descriptor.getTableName());
            descriptor.setTableName(tableName);
    }
 }
 }
```

and fire it from persistence.xml

```
<property name="eclipselink.session.customizer"  value="pl.....MySessionCustomizer" />
```

EDIT: people say UPPERCASE columns are orthodox. I use CamelCase in one JPA project, UPPER in other, historical dependency.
Some databases are strict (MS SQL Server), some not (Derby for column given without apostrophes?)